# Simple WebApp redirecting to wrong page

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have this simple redirect button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary mt-5 btn-rounded btn-lg" href="dashboard">Back to home</a>
```

It works perfectly if I'm on page: `mywebSite.com/user`

But If I'm on `mywebSite.com/user/John` when I click that button it redirects me to `mywebSite.com/user/dashboard`

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public ModelAndView dashboard() {
    return new ModelAndView("dashboard");
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: That's the correct behavior. Your `href` is relative to the current page. Use `href="/dashboard"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is a *relative link*. To fix this problem, simply switch it to `<a class="btn btn-primary mt-5 btn-rounded btn-lg" href="/dashboard">Back to home</a>`

Also switch every other occurrence of "dashboard" in your links to "/dashboard"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just `/dashboard` is enough. No need to make it website-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use a `base url`.

if you are using JSP you can use below code for setting base url.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.contextPath}" />
```

Now change your code as

```
<a class="btn btn-primary mt-5 btn-rounded btn-lg" href="${baseURL}/dashboard">Back to home</a>
```

If you are not using JSP youcan use javascript for the same-

Answer (score 0):

It is taking the relative path.Mention full URI in path ex: href="abc/xyz/cdfd/dashboard"